# How to show Date - Month in SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, date

I have date as `29/07/2017`. I have month count `10`.

How to show select difference between date and month?

```
select date-month from dual;  // this shows days difference.
```

I need to show month difference.

Comment: Is this Oracle?  Please tag, and show *real*  table column types and sample data.  Your question does not make sense.  You are trying to subract two different units.  Do you mean you want to subtract 10 months from a DATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you would need to extract `Month` from the date by:

```
SELECT MONTH(datefield) as Month
```

Taking your example in consideration:

```
SELECT MONTH('29/07/2017') as DateMonth
```

After this, you can subtract the above with `MonthCount`. I guess you can do the rest of it

As you can't directly subtract a `Date` and a Monthcount which is of `INT` type I assume, you would have to go with the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two SQL function to do it:

**DATEPART()**
**YEAR()** and **MONTH()**.

Thanks,
NS009

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Oracle and the date is stored as a date, you would use `add_months()`:

```
select add_months(datecol, -10)
```

In many other databases (and more recent versions of Oracle), you can use intervals:

```
select datecol - interval '10' month
```

If the value is a string, you need to convert it to a date.